# Javascript Does Not Run On Page Load

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

I have a Twirl template and in the `<head>` section I have the following code which works fine:

```
<head>
....
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascript/foo.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

However, when I subtitute the actual code in foo.js as follows (ie taking out the JS code in the public folder of the Play application and injecting it in the head as follows):

```
<head>
....
<script>
a bit of Javascript
</script>
...
</head>
```

The Javascript does not get run. Why does this happen?

**UPDATE**
I just check the console and I am getting this:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://www.gstatic.com https://cdn.firebase.com https://apis.google.com localhost:9001". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-T7q3kSCjCVu1y7HF82r83jYrT4MITeF5eVAUvhhNOUA='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Do you have errors in the browser console?

Comment: @VladuIonut see update

Comment: the CSP headers blocks the inline scripts, to allow scripts inline add the 'unsafe-inline' to CSP headers of the page. Check details on  [CSP: script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src)

Comment: yes I added the unsafe-inline but isn't this making my app vulnerable to XSS?

Comment: unfortunately it does, CSP headers are a safety net, though if the user input is validated and the output is encoded then XSS shouldn't happen. Check OWASP recommendations for preventing [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: @ValentinCarnu I will revert back to using the routes functionality in the playframework - that way I don't need to change the CSP to add unsafe-inline. That's too scary for me to do that.